# Accessing Instance Methods in a Rails AR Model Nested in a Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a gem that has an ActiveRecord model nested within a module like this:

```
module Fruit
  class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "weird_name_apples" # In case this is relevant
    ...
    def console_message
      puts "This should print a message to console."
    end
  end
end
```

When I open up a console in a sample app that has the gem installed and run the following:

```
Fruit::Apple.first.console_message
```

It returns `undefined method 'console_message' for #<Fruit::Apple:0x007fb58e19c48>`.

What's causing this error? In other apps, I can access instance methods from models just fine, but it's not in a gem nor using `table_name`, if that matters.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you get the same error if you add `console_message` as a class variable?

Comment: @MaxAlcala: Yes, I get the same error if I have it as a class method (e.g. `def self.console_message` and `Fruit::Apple.console_message`).

Comment: Maybe `console_message` is private?

Comment: @dimakura: No, it's not explicitly defined as a private method anywhere, unless that's something that automatically happens when nested in a module or when used as a gem?

Comment: I create a gist https://gist.github.com/dimakura/ae87d167c2b80b7bc4ae it's working perfectly.

Comment: @dimakura: Yes, that's what's confusing. It seems to be working in other projects, but not this one. The only differences are the `table_name` and the fact that it's a gem, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Justin the only way to help you is to see your code. Is it open source?